Template Argument Deduction Guides for Aliases
I want to deduce the template arguments of an aliased class template and Richard Smith says that should work in C++20.
If my alias is just a name-change, then this answer to a related question works with C++20:
template <typename T> struct Bar { Bar(T); };
template <typename T> using Foo = Bar<T>;

template <typename T> Bar(T) -> Bar<T>; // decuction guide here

Foo f{42};

However, my alias is not just a simple name-change, but something more involved, and I only want to deduce when used as alias. For the sake of argument, let's say:
template <typename T> struct MyVector{ MyVector(T); };
template <typename T> struct Bar { Bar(T); };
template <typename T> using BarVec = MyVector<Bar<T>>;

// how to tell the compiler that BarVec(int) should construct a
// MyVector<Bar<int>> without forcing all constructor calls for
// MyVector(int) to construct MyVector<Bar<int>> ?

// maybe like this?
template<typename T> BarVec(T) -> BarVec<T>;
// NO, error: "cannot specify deduction guide for alias template"

// suggested in the comments:
template<typename T> MyVector(T) -> MyVector<Bar<T>>;
// the compiler accepts this, but now all MyVector(T) calls create
// a MyVector<Bar<T>> which is not what I want

BarVec bv{42}; // I want this to deduce MyVector<Bar<int>>
MyVector mv{42} // I want this to deduce to MyVector<int>

See my attempts in inline comments. Play with it here.

You don't have an alias for a Bar, you have an alias for a std::vector.  You would have to make a deduction guide for std::vector which AFAIK is illegal to do.

@NathanOliver if I replaced std::vector with my own class, how would I write the deduction guide then?

The same way you did for Bar.  Your class would have to have a constructor that takes a T and then your deduction guide becomes something like template <typename T> MyClass(T) -> Myclass<Bar<T>>;

But I don't actually want to deduce all constructor calls MyClass(T) to dedude MyClass<Bar<T>> but only the aliased ones, that is, only when I call BarVec(T) shall the type be deduced as MyClass<Bar<T>>, not when I call MyClass(T) in general... Is that the core difference then?

CTAD for alias templates in C++20 does not permit declaring new deduction guides specific for the alias template. The deduction guides used for CTAD are instead derived from the class template that the alias template aliases. You can't make it deduce in the way you want.
